# TinyMCE on Gadget of EPiServer

Tags: tinymce, episerver, episerver-7

I wanna add the TinyMCE on my gadget on EPiServer. It's means I need stance directly the control.

```
<tinyMCE:Editor ID="myEditor" Width="300" Height="200" theme="simple" runat="server" ></tinyMCE:Editor>
```

but this just created a Text Area. How I can add all necessaries scripts?

Comment: Is the gadget for Online Center view or is the gadget part of your templates?

Comment: is a gadget in the EPiServer Dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add your own TinyMCE. That's the approach that's recommended for use in templates so this should be the same.

Comment: It's mean add the scripts to TinyMCE or add the TinyMCE in my solution like a duplicate files?

Comment: Yes, add your version separately. I would use the jQuery-plugin version of TinyMCE.